# How to make python run shell commands under /usr/bin instead of /bin/sh?

Tags: python, bash, path

first of all sorry if this question was asked I could not find any answers.

I have a Flask application served over `uwsgi` and `nginx` (not really relevant to my question).

The problem I am facing is that if I run:

```
os.system(f"grep {needle} /some/path/haystack.txt")
```

my server will output the following encountered error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: grep: not found.
```

If I run:

```
os.system(f"/usr/bin/grep {needle} /some/path/haystack.txt")
```

everything works as expected.

**I know that letting users run commands is insecure**: this is part of a hacking CTF I am developing for the company and they MUST be able to run commands, such as `;cat /tmp/flag.txt`.

I thought I could have a whitelist of commands such as `cat` `less` `more` etc, and if such a command is detected just replace it with the `/usr/bin/` variant, for example:

```
; cat /tmp/flag.txt
```

becomes

```
os.system(f"/usr/bin/grep ; /usr/bin/cat /tmp/flag.txt /some/path/haystack.txt")
```

However this is not ideal and I would like to tell Python to run commands without having to specify it should use /usr/bin.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to specify in the Python script to look at `/usr/bin` then an option would be to create a symlink to `/usr/bin` and then add the symlink to the `PATH` variable on the server and test.

First things first i would look into these file locations on the server, does `/usr/bin` exist on the server, or is it the Python script cannot, and then where the files actually are, if they do not exist on `/usr/bin`. In addition check which user you are running the script as, and check your permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will be trying your suggestion, the /usr/bin does exist and the user running it should have permissions. I have decided to go with the whitelist after all since I realised it's not that bad - having a whitelist with just a bunch of items such as 'cat, less, grep, more' and replacing them with their /usr/bin equivallents, everything is working as expected but I am going to look into the creation of the symlink and adding it to the PATH. Thank you!